# What is the meaning of the following statment from play! documentation?

Tags: java, playframework, promise

From [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync)

> Whether the action code returns a Result or a Promise, both
>   kinds of returned object are handled internally in the same way. There
>   is a single kind of Action, which is asynchronous, and not two kinds
>   (a synchronous one and an asynchronous one). Returning a Promise is a
>   technique for writing non-blocking code.

does this mean that there is no difference/advantage or disadvantage in returning a `Promise<Result>` rather than returning a `Result`? If play! framework encloses calls to `public static Result function()` in a `Promise`, is there a point in the developer explicitly returning  a `Promise<Result>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no point in *explicitly* returning a `Promise<Result>`, if what your code does is synchronous simply return a `Result`.

However, sometimes your code calls other code that returns a `Promise` because it performs a *non-blocking asynchronous operation*. In that case you should transform the promise to extract the information you need from it and then return it. By keeping it a `Promise` instead of unwrapping it - you're not forcing the thread to block and saving the overhead of a context switch which can be significant.

For example let's say you want to query a webservice:

```
WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url("someUrl");
Promise<JsonNode> json = holder.get();
```

Now, you *can* do the following:

```
JsonNode jsonResult = json.get(); // force the program to wait
return jsonResult; // return it
```

But this will force the thread to context-switch in a blocking io operation. Instead, you can return a promise directly:

```
return json; // return the promise
```

And save the overhead of context-switching, you can also use `.map` if you need to manipulate it first.

Comment: Benjamin, coming back to this question after some time, I have some more questions. I understand what you meant by `json.get();` will force the thread to context switch to a blocking I/O operation. But the I/O will have to happen eventually right? So some thread will block at some point of time?

Comment: I/O can happen without a thread blocking - this is called (unsurprisingly) non-blocking IO and it happens through an event system.

Comment: I have a  similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582411/how-to-convert-callback-to-a-promise. It would be great if you can lend a hand.